# text in center and icon at right end

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to put the text in center of the screen while the thumbnail is towards the right end of the screen, in the same line as text. However, the icon overlaps with the text. How can I move it to the right?

When I tried the same styling for Text instead of an icon, it seemed to work.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
         <View style={styles.topMiddleContainer}>
        <Text>All Locations</Text>
        {/* <Text style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          right: moderateScale(10)
        }}>ADD</Text> */}
        <TouchableOpacity
        >
          <IconFA name="plus" size={25} style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            right: moderateScale(0)
          }} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
  topMiddleContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
});
```

Codesandbox:

https://snack.expo.io/GWBrKI6F9

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move the styles of IconFA tag to TouchableOpacity.

```
 <TouchableOpacity
    style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        right: moderateScale(0)
      }}
    >
      <IconFA name="plus" size={25}  />
    </TouchableOpacity>
```